# Very few distinct prediction probabilities for CV instances with sparse SVM

Tags: scikit-learn

I’m having an issue using the prediction probabilities for sparse SVM, where many of the predictions come out the same for my test instances.  These probabilities are produced during cross validation, and when I plot an ROC curve for the folds, the results look very strange, as there are a handful of clustered points on the graph.  Here is my cross validation code, I based it off of the samples on the scikit website:

```
skf = StratifiedKFold(y, n_folds=numfolds)

for train_index, test_index in skf:
        #split the training and testing sets
        X_train, X_test = X_scaled[train_index], X_scaled[test_index]
        y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]

        #train on the subset for this fold
        print 'Training on fold ' + str(fold)
        classifier = svm.SVC(C=C_val, kernel='rbf', gamma=gamma_val, probability=True)
        probas_ = classifier.fit(X_train, y_train).predict_proba(X_test)

        #Compute ROC curve and area the curve
        fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, probas_[:, 1])
        mean_tpr += interp(mean_fpr, fpr, tpr)
        mean_tpr[0] = 0.0
        roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
```

I’m just trying to figure out if there’s something I’m obviously missing here, since I used this same training set and SVM parameters with libsvm and got much better results.  When I used libsvm and printed out the distances from the hyperplane for the CV test instances and then plotted the ROC, it came out much more like I expected, and a much better AUC.

Comment: slightly off topic, but worth mentioning: `sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=cv, scoring="roc_auc")` should help you reduce your for loop to one line, unless you need the intermediate values.

Comment: How many samples do you have in your test set? The ROC curve can only have as many distinct "steps" as you have samples in your test set.

Comment: Thanks for the one line implementation, I'll look at using that instead.  As far as number of instances, there are 20k instances total, 10k positive and 10k negative, and I'm using 5-fold cross-validation.  So that means that the test set for each fold has 4000 samples.  However, there are many values for which there are 1k-2k samples that all have the same prediction value, and there are only 3600 distinct prediction values over all of the folds for cross-validation.  The resulting ROC looks like five big stair steps, with some little bits of fuzziness around the inner corners.

Comment: If there are only 5-6 important unique prediction values then I would expect the same 5-6 step ROC as if there had been only 5-6 samples in the test set. Another point is that for your libsvm implementation you say you used used distance from the hyperplane to create your ROC curve, whereas here you are using actual probabilities created via `SVC`'s `predict_proba` method. To instead use distance from the hyperplane you should replace `classifier.fit(X_train, y_train).predict_proba(X_test)` with `classifier.fit(X_train, y_train).decision_function(X_test)`.

Comment: Unfortunately, decision_function() has not been implemented for sparse SVMs.  That was what I initially wanted to use as I wanted to avoid the computational overhead of the output probabilities.  Since I have thousands of sparse features, converting to a dense representation isn't really an option.

Comment: Ah, just gave it a try and I see what you mean. The documentation makes it seem like sparse matrices are fully supported.  Looks like you might be out of luck as far as that goes.